# How to get the timestamp of AWS APIGateway?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I want to record the time the AWS API gateway actually received the data.

How can I get that timestamp?

Comment: Can you let us know what the trigger you used?

Comment: @Cenxui Im using my client (eg: curl )to send request to  APIGateway. I want to track when my request hits the gateway. How can I get that timestamp from gateway?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to get the timestamp in client side?

Comment: @Cenxui not client side/. I think server side, because i want to read that from my lambda function and store it as a data at my dynamo db

Comment: I think that you should generate timestamp in your lambda function. There is no timestamp in template file of APIGateway.

Comment: Hope these comments will help you.